# my code to show and hide button doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button for my favourite items and I would like this button to change when I click on it. When the ajax call is successfull the button should be modified.
I have written this code but when I click the hide button, show button does not display.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com /ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$("#moins").click(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: { [this.id]: this.value },
  success: function(retour) {

$("#moins").hide();
$("#plus").show();

      }
    });
   return false;
  });
});

$(function() {
$("#plus").click(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: { [this.id]: this.value },
  success: function(retour) {

$("#plus").hide();
$("#moins").show();

      }
    });
   return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: post the html part too...

Comment: i uploaded post

Comment: I edited your description, see if I have understood what you were saying. confirm if it matches your wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're looking for.

For this you can use JQuerys `toggle()` function.
If given element is hidden, it will be displayed and vice-versa.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addFavourite").click(function() {

        // AJAX call to ADD to favourite

        // assuming it was successful
        // switch ICONS
        switchFavIcon($(".favIcon"));

    });

    function switchFavIcon(element){
        if(element.hasClass("far")){
            element.removeClass("far fa-heart");
            element.addClass("fas fa-heart");
        } else {
            element.removeClass("fas fa-heart");
            element.addClass("far fa-heart");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#addFavourite {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    color: #989898;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-+0VIRx+yz1WBcCTXBkVQYIBVNEFH1eP6Zknm16roZCyeNg2maWEpk/l/KsyFKs7G" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/regular.css" integrity="sha384-aubIA90W7NxJ+Ly4QHAqo1JBSwQ0jejV75iHhj59KRwVjLVHjuhS3LkDAoa/ltO4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-jLuaxTTBR42U2qJ/pm4JRouHkEDHkVqH0T1nyQXn1mZ7Snycpf6Rl25VBNthU4z0" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="addFavourite" data-action="addFav" type="button" name="button"><img src="" alt="">
   <i class="favIcon far fa-heart"></i>
  </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would like the same result but without favourites <li> i don't need that. in fact i have two button image at the same place i just would like when i click on  button "#moins"  he becomes hide and show the button "#plus" and this after the succes function

Comment: so only `1` button that can be changed to `show` or `hide` ? and you don't want the `li` to be there ? am i right? EDIT: or its fine to show both buttons and only view/hide `.favourites`?

Comment: you know it's a button like a heart to add items to favorites in database. So i need button who will add/remove items from database. When item is added the heart is pink and when the item is removed the heart is empty. i want that this function works on ajax

Comment: oh, i get it now. Ok will take a look into it

Comment: @mantraaxx check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/dha9r0b1/ let me know if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: yes it's something like this but how can i do if i have two buttons? 1 for add favorite and the second for remove favorite. I put the same class for the second button?

Comment: If you have two buttons then I guess there's no need for switching icons. am i right? and if that's not the case; what are you trying to achieve? hide one of them(as shown in the answer)?

Comment: Usually 1 button is used in order to make it userfriendly. Where filled icons mean " already added to favourites " and unfilled means " not added to favourites. ". I am not quite sure what you are looking for. Would you try to take a screenshot and show me waht you want it to look like ?

Comment: i tried tour code, it work fine but only little problem. when i click to favorite the item is add and the heart is full of color but if i refresh the page the heart back empty

Comment: (I am assuming you have login system) You need to check if session is active and look in the database after (posts/whatever) to confirm whether the user has added the "post" as favourite

Comment: If you could show your database & tables where you store this info i could help with that.

Comment: Oh yes§ it work fine! i just forgot to change the class in the session.

Comment: @mantraaxx I am glad it works for you :). Now please, since this answer works for your buttons you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Now everithing is Ok Thank you very very much! 2 weeks i was on this problem. you're the best! Thanks again